# Unlimited arbitrary properties (key/value pairs) for an ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, entity-attribute-value

Using ruby on rails, I have a Customer table that I want to be able to add unlimited properties (key value pairs) to. I'm not sure what the key/value pairs will be yet so I'm not sure how to do this. For example, one customer could be:

- Customer 1 properties:

  - color: 'yellow'
  - brand: 'nike'
  - sales: '33'
- Customer 2 properties:

  - color: 'red'
  - phone_number: '1111111111'
  - purchases: '2'

Basically, customers can have any number of properties in a key/value pair.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize) for this, and assign your properties hash to your properties attribute, and retrieve them in the same way.

Comment: This, however, will make it difficult, if not impossible, to query by those properties.

Comment: That depends on the database used. Postgres supports it easily - http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/02/using-postgress-hstore-with-rails/

Comment: Yes, if you install the gem.

Comment: That is "difficult, if not impossible"? Also, Rails 4 supports it natively. Why didn't you just point out that it might require the gem?

Comment: Because I didn't know about the gem, and not everyone uses Postgres? You answer was good, with caveats—I just wanted to make sure OP knew one of those caveats.

Comment: Right on, they are probably worth mentioning in the actual answer, for the reasons you mention...

Answer (score 11):

The "traditional" way to do this is with the Entity-Attribute-Value, or EAV pattern. As the name suggests, you'll create a new table with three columns: one for the "entity," which in this case is the Customer, one for the "attribute" name or key, and one for the value. So you'd have a table like this:

```
customer_properties
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+
| id | customer_id | key          | value      |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+
|  1 |           1 | color        | yellow     |
|  2 |           1 | brand        | nike       |
|  3 |           1 | sales        | 33         |
|  4 |           2 | color        | red        |
|  5 |           2 | phone_number | 1111111111 |
|  6 |           2 | purchases    | 2          |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

You'll definitely want an INDEX on `key` and *maybe* on `value` (and `customer_id`, of course, but Rails will do that for you when you use `relation` or `belongs_to` in your migration).

Then in your models:

```
# customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_properties
end

# customer_property.rb
class CustomerProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

This enables usage like this:

```
customer = Customer.joins(:customer_properties)
             .includes(:customer_properties)
             .where(customer_properties: { key: "brand", value: "nike" })
             .first

customer.customer_properties.each_with_object({}) do |prop, hsh|
  hsh[prop.key] = prop.val
end
# => { "color" => "yellow",
#      "brand" => "nike",
#      "sales" => "33" }

customer.customer_properties.create(key: "email", value: "foo@bar.com")
# => #<CustomerProperty id: 7, customer_id: 1, key: "email", ...>
```

As database design goes this is pretty solid, but as you can see it has some limitations: In particular, it's cumbersome. Also, you're restricted to a single value type (`:string`/`VARCHAR` is common). If you go this route you'll likely want to define some convenience methods on Customer to make accessing and updating properties less cumbersome. I'm guessing there are probably gems specifically for making the EAV pattern work nicely with ActiveRecord, but I don't know them off the top of my head and I hope you'll forgive me for not googling, since I'm mobile.

As Brad Werth points out, if you just need to store arbitrary properties and not query by them, `serialize` is a great alternative, and if you use PostgreSQL even the querying problem is surmountable thanks to its great hstore feature.

Good luck!

Comment: Right on, you've saved me the trouble - well said!

Comment: Wow, great answer (you too, brad). I used serialize but this is very interesting as well. thanks so much

Comment: Does anyone know of any standard Rails gems for using this pattern across multiple Rails models?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into the [hydra_attribute gem](https://github.com/kostyantyn/hydra_attribute/), which is an implementation of the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) pattern for ActiveRecord models.